# Redis data lost when stopping service

Tags: python, flask, redis

I have this python (Flask) platform that is using Redis for data management. https://github.com/murphyt7/projectHandover/blob/master/app.py

The problem is that when I restart the app.py all the information is lost. I heard that running BGSAVE command before that would solve the issue, but the problem is that the service restart is not predictable.

Is there a way to save data automatically in a persistent way?

Comment: Maybe you could try using RabbitMQ, is done to keep persistent queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Via Code**

Don't flush your database contents before or after execution of your application.

```
postRedisDB.flushall()
```

**Via Redis**

Also, configure your setup to persist via RDB or AOF (or both) so you're sure that you won't lose your data even in production mode

> RDB: Redis Database (Snapshot)
>   AOF: Append Only File (Operation Log)

For more information on Redis persistence, click here: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're killing redis forcefully your data shouldn't disappear. This, however...

Line 27:

```
postRedisDB.flushall()
```

[FLUSHALL](http://redis.io/commands/flushall):

> Delete all the keys of all the existing databases, not just the
>   currently selected one. This command never fails.